# How to change instance methods of a super class in subclasses?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

While i was doing exercises on inheritance concept of OOP, a question appeared in my mind, the question is about the below exercise:

```
import random
import time
class Character():
    Character_list = []

    def __init__(self, name, life=100, power=100):
        self.name = name
        self.life = life
        self.power = power

    def print(self):
        print("\n{}\n{} character details:".format("-" * 80, self.name))
        print("Name: {}\nLife: {}\nPower: {}\n{}".format(self.name, self.life, self.power, "-" * 80))

    def attack(self):
        attack = random.randrange(self.power + 1)
        if self.power <= 0:
            print("{} can't attack because power is empty".format(self.name))
            return False
        else:
            print("{} is attacking...".format(self.name))
            for i in range(80):
                time.sleep(0.05)
                print("-", end="", flush=True)
            self.power -= attack
            print("\n-  Spent power: {}".format(attack))
            print("-   Remaining power: {}\n".format(self.power))
            if attack == 0:
                print("{} missed.".format(self.name))
        return attack

    def attacked(self, attack):
        if attack != 0:
            print("{} injured.".format(self.name))
            self.life -= attack
            print("-  Remaining life: {}".format(self.life))
            if self.life <= 0:
                print("{} died.".format(self.name))
                self.Character_list.remove(self)


class Barbarian(Character):
    Character_list = []


class Wizard(Character):
    Character_list = []
```

The question i would like to ask about the above codes is: There’s a super class called Character. The later created Wizard and Barbarian subclasses inherit all the functions of the super class. Suppose to be that the name of the **power** instance attribute from the super class is different for each subclass. For example, for the Barbarian subclass, it is **strength**, and for the Wizard subclass it is **magic**  instead of  **power**.

Should instance methods of the super class be copied to the subclasses,  in order that each subclass uses the instance attribute of its own class instead of the **power** name, the super class instance methods should be renamed in the subclasses with their names changed? Or, for the action I want to do, how would you suggest a method other than rewriting the super class instance methods to subclasses by changing the name of the power? Thank you.

Comment: Why are your class/function definitions *inside a while loop*?

Comment: It's my mistake but my questions is different.

Comment: My advice is to create a *toy example*, and not dump your whole code. There's too much going on that is irrelevant to the core of your quesiton.

Comment: Ok, let me change the codes.

Comment: Your question mentions a power of "magic" or "strength" but your code shows an power attribute that is a numerical value. That's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes power attribute is a numerical value. And when the characters are created they have a power attribute with random numerical values. But my question is about can we change the name "power" to "strength" or "magic" depend on the sub classes without  re-writing the functions in the subclasses with the new power names. I tried to add property but after that the program gives an attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure - I'm a c# dev trying to answer a python question (so this answer may turn out to be unintentionally hilarious...)

The two easiest avenues I can think of:

A) Declare a variable in your base class and then change your constructor to require a 'PowerWord' be passed in (and then put its value into your variable.)  Any time anything tries to declare a new instance of some sort of character, they need to pass in what the PowerWord for that character will be (though I'd imagine you'd just have the derived classes pass it in.)

B) Use an abstract property.  This basically says, "Hey, if you want to write a class that derives from me, you'd better have a 'PowerWord' property."  Then, this lets you use that PowerWord up in the base class, without having to specify exactly what the PowerWord is (because every derived class will have an answer to what it's supposed to be.)

... anyway, yeah - you had the right idea.  You should *definitely* not copy/paste those functions into each derived class just to change 'power' to 'strength' or to 'magic'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your participation. Guess i understand what you tried to say. I will try to change the powerWord.